# Is it possible to MOUNT and entire external disk and not by partitions?

Tags: mount, partitioning, mountpoint

I want to mount an entire drive in read-only mode.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: And what do you want to achieve by that? You can only mount file systems and if a device has partitions containing the file systems, you may not directly mount the device. That's at least what I think, it might be wrong though...

Comment: @UTF-8 You can have an *unpartitioned* block device mounted as just one file system --- it was common with floppy disks. I still have an HP instrument using 3¼ floppy disks that I have to mount (through an USB interface) with `mount /dev/hdb /mnt`; the instrument do not create any partition table in it. Said that --- this is unseen since, I think, around 1995. Even USB sticks are partitioned today.

Comment: @Rmano It depends on how you view it. I use file containers with ext4 file systems in them and you can also mount dvd images. Whether you see them as a partition or not doesn't matter all that much. I seem them as 1 partition. This not only makes things easy but also is consequent since there can be partitions on different levels (primary and logical partition in devices with an msdos partition table). For me a partition is simply a peace of storage space with a file system on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Only file systems can be mounted and there is one per partition.

If you want to mount several partitions at once, that's possible, but they need different mounting points. Please write a comment if that's what you want.

If you want to delete all but one partition and make this one partition as big as the entire external HDD, that's also possible. Again, write a comment and I will help you.